# Byte array from C++/CLI to C

Tags: c, c++-cli, visual-c++-2012

I have a function in visual c++ something like this:

```
 DoSomething(IVector<unsigned char>^ inputBytes)
```

which is used to pass a byte array. And in this method i need to access a method of C class which accepts the byte array paramter(inputBytes). I have placed method like this in C class

```
 void TestFunction(unsigned char* testdata[])
```

but it throws an error.What is the syntax of the byte array in c. How to pass this bytearray from c++ to c. Can anyone please help me to find the solution.

Comment: This is C++/CLI question, right? If not, please roll back my edit.

Comment: IVector<> is a WinRT type which makes C++/CX the likely proper tag.  Please use correct tags, important to get an answer.  If correct, you'll have to copy the vector to an array, use the GetMany() method.  How that could possibly be a unsigned char*[] is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You declared array of pointers to char in your C function. I don't know C++/CLI, so not sure at all, but correct is one of these, I think:

```
void TestFunction(unsigned char* testdata)
```

or for many purposes exactly equal (subtle differences only):

```
void TestFunction(unsigned char testdata[])
```

First is pointer to char, or some number of chars, such as C style string. Second is array of some number of chars, which in C is almost same as pointer to char.

Most likely you need to add an int parameter, telling number of bytes, as C arrays do not know their own size (they are basically glorified pointers, as I said above), unless you can know the size some other way (like C strings end at first 0 byte).